# Is there is a way to use Google firebase elements in Google AMP?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, amp-html

I am working on page view count using firebase. It's work perfectly in non amp sites, but I cannot implement in AMP page, it leads to AMP errors

Is there is a way to use Google firebase project elements in Google AMP?